# using php to insert into mysql: access denied as root user

Tags: php, mysql, insert, connection

So I am using this script to try and insert into my local mysql database

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname_php'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname_php'];
$username = $_POST['username_php'];
$email = $_POST['email_php'];
$password = $_POST['password_php'];

// Create connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Insert user provided fields
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";

mysql_select_db('MyDatabase');
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
if(!$retval) {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I am getting the error: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

It seems as if the script isn't registering the login "root" and password "root" and defaulting to my username? I am not sure to be honest.

Comment: [generic sql injection warning]

Comment: Go ahead and post all of your database information here and then delete it before someone else does.

Comment: as in this isn't secure? Is there a simple way to make it secure? I need to call this script from AJAX because I have some client side processing.

Comment: These arent the correct credentials... I changed them when I posted

Comment: Sanitize your input on the server side. Setting the POST values to a variable does nothing except make typing a little easier.

Comment: Also, why are you mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`?

Comment: @AlekHurst Googling "sql injection" will take you a long way. Use prepared statements. If I knew where your site was, I could easily write my own database query and enter it as my username.

Comment: I am sanitizing it before it even reaches this point.

Comment: @AlekHurst That doesn't work. What is stopping a person from accessing this file directly, or modifying the javascript running their browser to bypass the filter?

Comment: Not to mention an HTTP request can come from outside the scope of your other page, so it would skip it entirely

Comment: @m59 ohhhhhh, that totally makes sense. Definitely forgot to think about that. Thanks for bringing it up! I will add my sanitation to the server side. But my question here is still the same.

Comment: @AlekHurst not sanitation - prepared statements. Sanitation = maybe I don't get attacked. Prepared statements = can't get attacked.

Comment: so simply moving my regex's to this page on the _POST variables prior to entering them in the database will do the trick, correct?

Comment: Also PBKDF2. Google is good. https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: @m59 sorry I sent that last message before I saw your message about prepared statements. I will look into prepared statements before I bring the site live. Right now I just need to be able to connect and store data and I will build up from there.

Answer (score 2):

// Create connection
`$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root");`

You forgot to specify the database you want to connect to as the last parameter

should be:

`$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "database_name");`

See if this solves your problem. :D

Comment: After doing this, the error changes to "Cannot enter data: " ... very helpful error message... haha

Comment: @AlekHurst $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";   In your database are the column names actually user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password ? try leaving these off and do the INSERT by just specifying values. :D

Comment: @Alex http://us2.php.net/mysql_query  read this and see if you are missing something *thumbs up*

Comment: my password column is user_password. I am not sure if I understand correctly.

Comment: and I am getting the same error after changing to mysqli_query()

Comment: @Alex change the code to `mysqli_query($sql, $connection) or die ('something went wrong');`

Comment: @AlekHurst well the query does not have to specify column names but if you go this way you have to list each column, so you could write:`$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";` See what I mean?

Comment: @AlexHurst what does your users database table look like?

Comment: @AlekHurst also I think your syntax is a little off. it should be something like `mysqli_query($dbc, $query);` where the database connection is specified as the first parameter then the SQL query as a PHP variable. :D

Comment: user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_username, user_email, user_password

Comment: tried to change the insert to match the database format as well as take away the single quotes, still no worky.

Comment: is the user_id auto increment? put 0 as a place holder if so in the first argument so it is `$sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES(0, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";`

Comment: something that strikes me as a little weird is that I have a success function in the AJAX that calls this script and its "success" message is printing with the die message following it.

Comment: @AlekHurst is anything in your database? Does it actually INSERT? 0_o

Comment: hmm, it is still giving me the die message after I implemented it in that way

Comment: @Alex you could add back on the `mysql_error()` you had to get more detailed error reporting

Comment: There is actually a users table in the database you are connected to?

Comment: @Alex the problem is the SQL. Either the columns specified do not match your database schema exactly, or the table does not exist, or the table is not in the database you are connecting to, or there is a spelling error. Try a very simple query and see if it works. Then you could try something more complex. :D

Answer (score 1):

I can't post a comment, but user2085446 has it right.

you are also mixing mysql_.. with mysqli..  these are entirely different connectors.

So, in your original script, you were connecting with mysqli_connect but then using mysql_select_db...  This is where the error was coming from - the mysql_select_db.  if you change the call to mysqli_select_db([conn id], [db name]) that particular error will resolve itself.  But, you can also bypass the need for the additional call by passing the dbname with the initial mysqli_connect(..).

I recommend taking a look at this page which provides you with a nice example of how to properly use the mysqli connector.  It will make your life much easier and you will be able to properly see the errors mysql throws if any occur.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: I will take a look at that, thank you. I changed them all to mysqli for now, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I use XAMPP which comes with MySQL (among other things, most notably Apache server).

https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html <-- Download from there.

Load up the control panel, click Admin. Should load a webpage, then click Add User.

Make sure you don't give that user all permissions or it has a cry(error) I got ride of Shutdown.

So now i have a user with everything I need that has a password.

When logging in, mysql -u (username) -p
Then will be asked for password.

Hope that helps. =D